# A word replacer that uses an API to check for different words to make up a new string

Tags: python, python-2.x, api

This is one of my first finished programs that I've written to date. I am not yet very familiar with Python, so please bear with me.

I'd like to know from you:

- Can my code be called 'pythonic'?

  - I've tried to get rid of calling arrays via index variables as much as possible
  - I've also tried to use Python specific functions rather than to build new, redundant ones
- Is my exception logic too confusing? - If so, how to improve on that?
- Is there any way to make my code more efficient?
- Is my documenting style helpful?

#### word_replacer.py

```
import API
import re
from nltk import pos_tag
import sys
from pathlib2 import Path

def sanitize_for_url(word):
    """
    Sanitizing of a word with a regex search string - everything that is not alphanumeric, a space or a colon is
    substituted by an empty set
    Args:
        word (str): Word to sanitize
    Returns:
        str: Sanitized string
    """
    return re.sub('[^a-zA-Z\s:]', '', word)


def remove_escapes(word):
    """
    Removes escape backslashes that are created by various security mechanisms
    Args:
        word (str): Word to sanitize
    Returns:
        Sanitized string
    """
    return re.sub(r'\\', '', word)


def fetch_words(url):
    """
    Retrieving a json result set from the API module
    An API object is instantiated and a json result set is returned by calling
    the instance specific API.object.getr() function
    Args:
        url (str): URL string to instantiate the API object
    Returns:
        dict: JSON data as python dictionary
    """
    api = API.API(url, False, '')
    return api.getr()

def find_max_len(text):
    """
    A linear search of the maximum length of a particular string
    Every string in the array is looked up by its length and consequently compared
    The string with the biggest length is then returned
    Args:
        text (arr[str]): array of strings that are compared
    Returns:
        str: Word with the biggest length
    """
    max_length = ''
    for i in text:
        if len(i) > len(max_length):
            max_length = i
    return max_length

def find_new_word(words, word_type):
    """
    Checks if the word type is found in the words dict. If so the word with the biggest length is chosen
     and returned
    Args:
        words (dict): A json result set as dict
        word_type (str): The specific word type - this is actually needed as the key in the json result set dict
    Raises:
        API.requests.exceptions.HTTPError: If the key is not found in the dict (and therefore the word type is
        non-existent) - a requests.exceptions.HTTPError is raised for easier logic in the run function
    Returns:
        str: New word
    """
    word_categories = ["sim", "syn"]
    word_list = words.get(word_type, "")
    for tag in (x for x in word_categories if x in word_list):
        new_word = find_max_len(word_list)
        return new_word
    raise API.requests.exceptions.HTTPError

def run(text):
    """
    Main function that brings everything together - the first part of the URL is used as a parameter for the instantiation
    of the API object. The string (that may be multiple sentences) is then replaced by calling other functions.
    First the string is assigned to an array of strings calling splice_words(str). Then a tuple is assigned by
    calling NLTK.pos_tag(arr[str]). A loop to the length of the text array is then started - checking if the particular word
    is a word in the standard list - check_standard(tuple[str, str]). If not, the sanitization method clean_word[str] is called
    and the URL build. The new word is then appended to the result array. If an exception was raised, all operations are skipped
    and the unchanged word is added to the result array.
    If the API comes to a halt (due to processing limits of the API key), an empty file is set to ensure stopping
    and not spamming the server for the time being.
    Args:
        baseurl (str): URL to instantiate the API object
        text (str): String to replace the words from
    Returns:
        Result string if no ValueError has been found, error message if otherwise
    """
    baseurl = "http://words.bighugelabs.com/api/2/0311fc4c609183416bf8bae6780fb886/{}/json"
    if len(text) <= 500:
        try:
            compare = pos_tag(text.split())
            result = []
            for word, tag in compare:
                if check_standard_word(tag):
                    result.append(word)
                else:
                        url_word = sanitize_for_url(word)
                        if not url_word: continue
                        url = baseurl.format(url_word)
                        try:
                            new_word = find_new_word(fetch_words(url), determine_word_type(tag))
                            match = re.match('[\.,\-\?\!\(\)]', word[-1])
                            if match:
                                result.append(new_word + match.group()) # only copies over the last character plus the new word
                            else:
                                result.append(new_word)
                        except API.requests.exceptions.HTTPError:
                            result.append(word) # old, unchanged word
                            continue
            return remove_escapes(' '.join(result))
        except ValueError:
            Path("/var/www/.inactive").touch()
            return "Try again later. API processing limit reached."
    else: return "The text you are typing is too long to process. Sorry."

def check_standard_word(tag):
    """
    Checks if the values from the compare tuple are found in the exclude array
    Args:
        tag (str): Tag from nltk.pos_tag(arr[str]) function
    Returns:
        bool: If found in the array return True, False if otherwise
    """
    exclude = ["MD", "DT", "PRP", "$PRP", "IN", "CC", "CD", "EX", "NNP", "NNPS", "POS", "PDT", "RP", "WDT", "SYM", "TO"]

    if tag in exclude: return True
    else: return False

def omitted_words(words):
    """
    Checks if new selected word is a composition of multiple words which might include
    nonsensical grammatical words which are substituted by an empty set. First regex check is to ensure the new word
    actually has spaces
    Args:
        words(str): Sequence of words with spaces
    Returns:
        str: The word either unchanged or with the substitution of the grammatical words
    """
    if re.match('\w+\s', words):
        compare = pos_tag(splice_words(clean_word(words)))
        for word, tag in compare:
            if check_standard(tag):
                print word
                words = words.replace(word, '')
    return words

def determine_word_type(tag):
    """
    Determines the word type by checking the tuple created by the nltk.pos_tag(arr[str]) function. 
    Each word in the array is marked with a special tag which can be used to find the correct type of a word.
    A selection is given in the arrays.
    Args:
        compare (tuple[str]): Tuple of strings - the word is in the first row, the tag in the second
    Returns:
        str: Word type as a string
    """
    noun = ["NN", "NNS", "NNPS", "FW"]
    adjective = ["JJ", "JJR", "JJS"]
    verb = ["VB", "VBD", "VBG", "VBN", "VBP", "VBZ"]
    adverb = ["RB", "RBR"]

    if tag in noun: return "noun"
    elif tag in adjective: return "adjective"
    elif tag in verb: return "verb"
    elif tag in adverb: return "adverb"
    else: return "noun"

inactive_switch = Path("/var/www/.inactive")
if inactive_switch.is_file():
    print "Try again later. API processing limit reached."
    sys.exit()
if len(sys.argv) > 1: print run(sys.argv[1])
```

#### API.py

```
import requests
import argparse

"""
This module is a library for a typical API application
There are different variables to set 
"""

class API(object):
    __xrequest = ''
    __api_key = ''
    params = {}
    def __init__(self, url, xrequest, api_key, **params):
        """
        Init function of the API class
        Args:
            url (str): URL for the API to call
            xrequest (bool): Switch if x-request is needed
            api_key (str): API-key as a string
            **params (dict): More parameters for the class to parse in the URL
        Returns:
            API.object: Instance of the API class
        """

        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='API library that works with requests')
        parser.add_argument('text', nargs='*')
        args = parser.parse_args()

        self.url = url
        self.__xrequest = xrequest
        self.__api_key = api_key
        self.params = params

    def find_error(self, request):
        """
        Find-error function that is used to check the json return dict for any error messages
        Args:
            request (request instance): Instance of the request class
        Returns:
            bool: True for success, False otherwise
        """
        if 'message' or 'error' in request:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def getr(self):
        """
        Get request function to build a URL and instantiate a request object with a json result set
        Returns:
            dict: content of the json-page decoded with the requests.object.json() function
        """
        if len(self.params) > 0:
            for key, value in self.params.iteritems():
                self.url += '?' + key + '=' + value
        if self.__xrequest == True:
            self.__xrequest = {'x-api-key': ''}
            self.__xrequest['x-api-key'] = self.__api_key
            r = requests.get(self.url, headers=self.__xrequest, allow_redirects=False)
            r.raise_for_status()
            if r.status_code == 303: raise requests.exceptions.HTTPError
            else: return r.json()
        else:
            r = requests.get(self.url)# ,allow_redirects=False)
            self.find_status(r, 500)
            r.raise_for_status()
            #if r.status_code == 303: raise requests.exceptions.HTTPError
            return r.json()

    def find_status(self, request, status):
        """
        Find status function that checks for a certain status in the requests.object.status_code int and raise a ValueError accordingly
        Args:
            request (requests object): Requests object
            status (int): Desired status to raise an exception for
        Raises:
            ValueError
        """
        if request.status_code == status:
raise ValueError
```

The repository can be found [here on github](https://github.com/Fuchus/Word-Replacer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks nice.

Here are a few detais:

### In `find_max_len`

The name `max_length` suggests an positive integer value corresponding to a length. We actually use it for a string, which may be slightly confusing.

At every iteration, you compute the length of 2 strings which is probably more than required for an optimal strategy.

You are lucky because the problem you are trying to solve has a generic solution : [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#max) which in your case gives `return max(text, key=len, default='')` (I've kept `''` as a default value as it corresponds to the current behavior but maybe an exception is a more desirable way to handle an empty list).

### In `sanitize_for_url`

The docstring says "alphanumeric" but the regexp does not include numbers. Also, if your pont is just to make an URL from a string, you may find better option in the [`urllib.parse` module](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode).

### In `check_standard_word`

You could write: `return tag in exclude`.

### In `determine_word_type`

Instead of using lists, you could use sets which is a data type more relevant to what you are trying to achieve.

Also, you may want to replace the code with a dictionnary structure:

```
def determine_word_type(tag):
    types = {
        'adjective': {"JJ", "JJR", "JJS"},
        'verb': {"VB", "VBD", "VBG", "VBN", "VBP", "VBZ"},
        'adverb': {"RB", "RBR"},
        'noun': {"NN", "NNS", "NNPS", "FW"},
    }
    for type_, set_ in types.iteritems():
        if tag in set_:
            return type_
    return 'noun'
```

Also, if you want to make lookup faster, you could build a dictionnary from the initial dict mapping word to their types:

```
def determine_word_type(tag):
    types = {
        'adjective': {"JJ", "JJR", "JJS"},
        'verb': {"VB", "VBD", "VBG", "VBN", "VBP", "VBZ"},
        'adverb': {"RB", "RBR"},
        'noun': {"NN", "NNS", "NNPS", "FW"},
    }
    types2 = dict()
    for type_, set_ in types.iteritems():
        for e in set_:
            assert e not in types2
            types2[e] = type_
    return types2.get(tag, 'noun')
```

(You'd need the dict building part to be moved out of the function to be performed only once).